# Where should I pass pre trained word embedding in a encoder-decoder architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, word-embedding, machine-translation

I have  pre-trained word embeddings from two different languages using MUSE. Now suppose I have a encoder-decoder architecture. And I created a embedding layer from one of this embedding. But where do I pass it in the model?

The model is trying to translate from one language to another. I have created a embedding_layer. Where do I pass it in in the below code?

```
""" 
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

# Run training
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy') 
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2)
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs of keras: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/

If you have the whole model saved, you can load the model using the command

```
keras.models.load_model(filepath)
```

This is the code example from the Kera docs:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

If you have just only the weights, You can use this command:

```
model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```